# php SoapClient parameter sequence with the same name

Tags: php, soap-client

I've to do a soap call where the parameter contains a sequence of complex type.

I don't find the good format for the parameter.

Here the xsd :

```
<xs:complexType name="createOspService">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="OSP" type="tns:OSP" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="ospServiceResponse">
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="OSP">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="OSP_ID" type="xs:int" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
        <xs:element name="DATE_OSP" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
        <xs:element name="CUSTOMER_ID" type="xs:int" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
        <xs:element name="RECIPIENT_ID" type="xs:int" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
        <xs:element name="ITEMS" type="tns:ITEMS" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="ITEMS">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="ITEM" type="tns:ITEM" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="ITEM">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="OSP_ITEM" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
        <xs:element name="QUANTITY" type="xs:double" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
        <xs:element name="UNIT_PRICE" type="xs:double" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
        <xs:element name="VAT_CODE" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

The php call :

```
$client = new \SoapClient('http://10.55.12.90:18180/NABSCamel/lgg/osp/ws?wsdl', $options);
try {
    $osp = new \stdClass();
    $osp->OSP = new \stdClass();
    $osp->OSP->OSP_ID = $this->meetingRoomBookingI;
    $osp->OSP->DATE_OSP = $date->format('c');
    $osp->OSP->CUSTOMER_ID = $customer->Id();
    $osp->OSP->RECIPIENT_ID = $recipientId;

    $items = [];

    $item = new \stdClass();
    $item->OSP_ITEM = 'test 1';
    $item->VAT_CODE = 21;
    $item->QUANTITY = 2;
    $item->UNIT_PRICE = 3;

    $items[] = $item;

    $item = new \stdClass();
    $item->OSP_ITEM = 'test 2';
    $item->VAT_CODE = 21;
    $item->QUANTITY = 2;
    $item->UNIT_PRICE = 3;

    $items[] = $item;

    $osp->OSP->ITEMS = $items;

    $response = $client->createOspService($osp);
} 
catch (\SoapFault $fault){
    echo $fault->faultstring;
}
```

I got this error :

```
SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no 'ITEM' property
```

I don't find what it's missing something near ITEMS parameter.

ITEMS must be an array with ITEM but where I put this word ITEM in my array ?!

thanks,
Phil

Answer (score 0):

If you really don't know how to construct the request and don't want to wonder, then you should definitively use a WSDL to PHP generator that'll generate the associated classes. You won't have to wonder how to construct the request as you'll have each class for each struct. Moreover, the response handling will be easier too.

I suggest you tru the [PackageGenerator](https://github.com/WsdlToPhp/PackageGenerator) project which is a good generator.

Comment: Thanks! I use the tool to generate the classes to see the structure i have to use.
And I haven't the error